# How to import numeric data with 00 as prefix correctly in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example my data set has `00501`, `00544`

After importing as a dataframe it becomes as shown below

```
    0    501
    1    544

Name: VALUE, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If leading 0s matter, it's string data, not numeric data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that is zip code , so nchar should equal to 5

```
df.v.astype(str).str.rjust(5,'0')
Out[101]: 
0    00501
1    00544
Name: v, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zfill`:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As by previuos comment if you're reading from a file `data.csv` where on the given columns you have leading 0s you might consider to read it using

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype="object")
```